# Populate html table headers based upon dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I am still learning web dev.

Thank you all for your feedbacks...

> I would like to choose a month `(MMMM-YYYY)` from a dropdown and get the html table headers to display the month `M`, the last month `M-1`, `M-3`, `M-6`, `M-11` and `M-12`
>
> In other words. From the dropdown, if I selected **June 2018**
>
> the table headers would be:
>
> `June 2018 | May 2018 | March 2018 | December 2017 | July 2017 | June 2017`

- I tried to approach the problem by row first (I just started learning JS) and **I stuck on how to flip it.**

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title> Untitled </title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>
      <form onsubmit="return false">

      <span class="bgthead" >
       <select name="features" onchange="alterColumn(this.selectedIndex)">
         <option value="1">June 2018</option>
         <option value="2">May 2018</option>
         <option value="3">April 2018</option>
       </select>
      </span>

      <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="tblBody">
         <tr>
           <td class="alt">June 2018</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="alt">May 2018</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="alt">March 2018</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="alt">December 2017</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="alt">July 2017</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td class="alt">June 2017</td>
         </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
       </form>
  ```
- The JS part is below:

```
var columnValues = [
   ["June 2018","May 2018", "March 2018", "December 2017", "July 2017", "June 2017"],
   ["May 2018", "April 2018", "February 2018", " November 2017", "June 2017", "May 2017"],
   ["April 2018", "March 2018", " January 2017", "October 2017", "May 2017", "April 2017"]
];

function alterColumn(grp) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('tblBody').getElementsByTagName('td');
  var k = 0;  grp = Number(grp);  
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    if (sel[i].className == 'alt') { sel[i].innerHTML = columnValues[grp][k]; 
k++; }}}
```

- The goal is to have an html table with cells that are filled with data coming from a DB using php. **data in table cells changing according to the month displayed in the headers.**
- The dropdown can be built using the month column in the database table.
- my only issue was/is the dynamic table header part using the dropdown...

Thank you again for your feedbacks, corrections... I am learning... I am growing.

Take care!

Comment: You need to show us your effort - Stackoverflow does not offer ready to use solutions

Comment: We need more information regarding how the dropdown is built, an example of one, how the table is built, an example of one, and any logic you have written in an attempt to solve this already.

Answer (score 1):

You can give each `select` option a value that reflects the month and the year with a space between with which the String can be split. You can then create a new `Date` object with the month and year and subtract the number of months you want from it each time (after recreating the `Date` object).

```js
showChange();

function showChange() {
  var date = document.getElementById('dates').value;
  var split = date.split(' ');
  date = new Date(split[1], parseInt(split[0]) - 1, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  var month = date.getMonth();
  document.getElementById("1").textContent = formatDate(date);
  date.setMonth(month - 1);
  document.getElementById("2").textContent = formatDate(date);
  date = new Date(split[1], parseInt(split[0]) - 1, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  date.setMonth(month - 3);
  document.getElementById("3").textContent = formatDate(date);
  date = new Date(split[1], parseInt(split[0]) - 1, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  date.setMonth(month - 6);
  document.getElementById("4").textContent = formatDate(date);
  date = new Date(split[1], parseInt(split[0]) - 1, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  date.setMonth(month - 11);
  document.getElementById("5").textContent = formatDate(date);
  date = new Date(split[1], parseInt(split[0]) - 1, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
  document.getElementById("6").textContent = formatDate(date);
}

function formatDate(date) {
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  return monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<select onchange="showChange()" id="dates">
  <option value="6 2018">June 2018</option>
  <option value="5 2018">May 2018</option>
  <option value="4 2018">April 2018</option>
</select>
<p/>
<table id="date">
  <tr>
    <th id="1"></th>
    <th id="2"></th>
    <th id="3"></th>
    <th id="4"></th>
    <th id="5"></th>
    <th id="6"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this script you should be able to accomplish what you want.

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var selectedDate = 'June 2018'; //Selected month from dropdown
var selectedMonth = selectedDate.split(' ')[0]; //Get the data before the frist ' '
var selectedYear = selectedDate.split(' ')[1]; //Get the data after the frist ' '
var wantedMonths = [0, -1, -3, -6, -11, -12]; //List of the month you want

var monthNumber = months.indexOf(selectedMonth); //Returns the month number - 1 (arrays start at 0)
monthNumber++ //True month number

for (i = 0; i < wantedMonths.length; i++) { //Display each month
    if (monthNumber + wantedMonths[i] > 0) { //Check if we'll have to go back a year
        table[i].innerHTML =  months[monthNumber + wantedMonths[i] - 1] + ' ' + selectedYear; //Ouput the month and year
    } else { //Not in the same year
        table[i].innerHTML =  months[(monthNumber + 12) + wantedMonths[i] - 1] + ' ' + (selectedYear - 1); //Taking year, giving 12 months
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS Explanation, first I selected the entire table (`table`), you may want to select just the row. Then there is a list of the months (`months`) which is used through out the script. After that there is the data from the drop down (`selectectedDate`)(I just defined in JS for simplification). Then I split is by the space giving me the month and year in separate variables (`selectedMonth` and `selectedYear`). Then the list of months that you want outputted repetitive to the selected month (`wantedMonths`). Then I get the month number (`monthNumber`) using the array of months. Then the script loops through the wanted months and outputs them to the table checking if it should go back a year or not. If you have any questions let me know.